# Splitting the unit segment into two parts recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I would like to create a simple multifractal (Binomial Measure). It can be done as follows:

> The binomial measure is a probability measure which is defined conveniently via a recursive construction. Start by splitting $ I := [0, 1] $ into two subintervals $ I_0 $ and $ I_1 $ of equal length and assign the masses $ m_0 $ and $ m_1 = 1 - m_0 $ to them. With the two subintervals one proceeds in the same manner and so forth: at stage two, e.g. the four subintervals $ I_{00}, I_{01}, I_{10}, I_{11} $ have masses $ m_0m_0, m_0m_1 m_1m_0 m_1m_1 $ respectively.

[Rudolf H. Riedi. Introduction to Multifractals](http://www.stat.rice.edu/~riedi/Publ/PDF/intro.pdf)

And it should look like this on the 13 iteration:
[image: Figure 1]

I tried to implement it recursively but something went wrong: it uses the previously changed interval in both left child and the right one

```
def binom_measuare(iterations, val_dct=None, interval=[0, 1], p=0.4, temp=None):

    if val_dct is None:
        val_dct = {str(0.0): 0}

    if temp is None:
        temp = 0

    temp += 1

    x0 = interval[0] + (interval[1] - interval[0]) / 2
    x1 = interval[1]

    print(x0, x1)

    m0 = interval[1] * p
    m1 = interval[1] * (1 - p)

    val_dct[str(x0)] = m0
    val_dct[str(x1)] = m1

    print('DEBUG: iter before while', iterations)
    while iterations != 0:

        if temp % 2 == 0:
            iterations -= 1
            print('DEBUG: iter after while (left)', iterations)
            # left
            interval = [interval[0] + (interval[1] - interval[0]) / 2, interval[1] / 2]
            binom_measuare(iterations, val_dct, interval, p=0.4, temp=temp)

        elif temp % 2 == 1:
            print('DEBUG: iter after while (right)', iterations)
            # right
            interval = [interval[0] + (interval[1] - interval[0]) / 2, interval[1]]
            binom_measuare(iterations, val_dct, interval, p=0.4, temp=temp) 

    else:
        return val_dct
```

Also, I have tried to do this using for-loop and it is doing good job up to the second iteration: on the third iteration it uses 2^3 multipliers rather than 3 $ m_0m_0m_0 $ and 2^4 on the fourth rather than 4 and so on:

```
iterations = 4
interval = [0, 1]
val_dct = {str(0.0): 0}
p = 0.4

for i in range(1, iterations):
    splits = 2 ** i
    step = interval[1] / splits
    print(splits)

    for k in range(1, splits + 1):
        deg0 = splits // 2 - k // 2
        deg1 = k // 2
        print(deg0, deg1)
        val_dct[str(k * step)] = p ** deg0 * (1 - p) ** deg1
    print(val_dct)
```

The concept seems very easy to implement and probably someone has already done it. Am I just looking from another angle?

---

UPD: Please, may sure that your suggestion can achieve the results that are illustrated in the Figure above (`p=0.4, iteration=13`).

UPUPD: [Bill Bell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939392/3671347) provided a nice idea to achieve what Riedi mentioned in the article. I used Bill's approach and wrote a function that implements it for needed number of iterations and $m_0$ (please see my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42947670/3671347)).

Comment: Please note that your *specific* question deals with with duplicating the interval in the left and right children.  This is focused and described well for Stack Overflow's stated purpose.  However, your follow-up comment suggests that any answer has to fix whatever else might be wrong with your program.  *That* is too broad for SO -- diagnosis of unreported problems is *your* responsibility, not ours.  However, I'm glad that you and @Bill Bell nailed everything you need.

Comment: @Prune I might not understand you correctly but my follow-up comment to your answer was meant to notify that I have not achieved what was asked in the question in the first place. I am not as experienced as you on SX by any means but I believe that every answer should contain at least a tiny insight regarding the problem that the author occurred otherwise there is no point in posting it. Your answer helped me to deal with unmentioned infinite while-loop, thanks! Don't you think you should post it in the comment section to the question? Please let me know if I did not understand what you meant.

Comment: Oh -- I thought you got the original results.  No, my answer does not get you all the way to a solution.  Do you still need help with this?

Comment: @Prune I would be very happy to see how to fix the problem that associates with the fact that my version of a program calculates only one branch of the whole tree.

Comment: Okay; I'll keep this on my active stack.  No time today; sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the principle correctly you could use the sympy symbolic algebra library for making this calculation, along these lines.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('m0 m1')
(m0, m1)
>>> layer1 = [m0, m1]
>>> layer2 = [m0*m0, m0*m1, m0*m1, m1*m1]
>>> layer3 = []
>>> for item in layer2:
...     layer3.append(m0*item)
...     layer3.append(m1*item)
...     
>>> layer3
[m0**3, m0**2*m1, m0**2*m1, m0*m1**2, m0**2*m1, m0*m1**2, m0*m1**2, m1**3]
```

The intervals are always of equal size.

When you need to evaluate the distribution you can use the following kind of code.

```
>>> [_.subs(m0,0.3).subs(m1,0.7) for _ in layer2]
[0.0900000000000000, 0.210000000000000, 0.210000000000000, 0.490000000000000]
```

Comment: It is pretty much what I needed. It is simple and elegant though it uses another package. I tried to generalize this concept in my answer I assume that you do not mind.

Comment: Not at all! My answer was merely a sketch.

Comment: by the way, do you have any ideas how to generalize it to a 2-dimensional case? I tried to specify 4 vars (instead of 2: m0, m1), append to 4 of them in the loop, and added to subs into a final for-comprehension. It gives long list of values and I have no idea how to split it somewhat reasonably.

Comment: You should, please, ask another question. If you comment here I think I can give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in your while loop: it doesn't properly handle the base case of your recursion.  It stops only when **iterations** is 0, but keeps looping otherwise.  If you want to debug why this forms an infinite loop, I'll leave it to you.  Instead, I did my best to fix the problem.

I changed the **while** to a simple **if**, made the recursion a little safer by not changing **iterations** within the routine, and made **interval** a local copy of the input parameter.  You're using a mutable object as a default value, which is dangerous.

```
def binom_measuare(iterations, val_dct=None, span=[0, 1], p=0.4, temp=None):
    interval = span[:]
    ...
    ...
print('DEBUG: iter before while', iterations)
if iterations > 0:

    if temp % 2 == 0:
        print('DEBUG: iter after while (left)', iterations)
        # left
        interval = [interval[0] + (interval[1] - interval[0]) / 2, interval[1] / 2]
        binom_measuare(iterations-1, val_dct, interval, 0.4, temp)

    else:
        print('DEBUG: iter after while (right)', iterations)
        # right
        interval = [interval[0] + (interval[1] - interval[0]) / 2, interval[1]]
        binom_measuare(iterations-1, val_dct, interval, 0.4, temp)

else:
    return val_dct
```

This terminates and seems to give somewhat sane results.  However, I wonder about your interval computations, when the right boundary can often be less than the left.  Consider [0.5, 1.0] ... the left-child recursion will be on the interval [0.75, 0.5]; is that what you wanted?

Comment: unfortunately, I could not achieve the needed results by doing the suggested fixes. Can you please provide me with the code that you used to obtain your results. When I run `binom_measuare(iterations=2)` I receive `{'0.5': 0.3, '0.625': 0.2, '0.0': 0, '1': 0.6, '0.75': 0.4}` (so it does not go to left child in the first place: we should also receive values for .125, .250, .375). Maybe I just cannot copy&paste the code or it does not fix my problem. Using your code, can you achieve the results that are illustrated in the figure in the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is my adaptation of [@Bill Bell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939392/3671347)'s answer to my question. It generalizes the idea that he provided.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import var

def binom_measuare(iterations, p=0.4, current_layer=None):

    var('m0 m1')

    if current_layer is None:
        current_layer = [1]

    next_layer = []

    for item in current_layer:
        next_layer.append(m0*item)
        next_layer.append(m1*item)

    if iterations != 0:
        return binom_measuare(iterations - 1, current_layer=next_layer)

    else:
        return [i.subs(m0, p).subs(m1, 1 - p) for i in next_layer]
```

Let's plot the output

```
y = binom_measuare(iterations=12)
x = [(i+1) / len(y) for i in range(len(y))]

x = [0] + x
y = [0] + y

plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

I think we have it.