# Splitting the unit segment into two parts recursively (2-D case)

Tags: python, numpy, recursion

Recently I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42938028/3671347) about how to generate a simple multifractal (Binomial Measure) in 1-D and I received a nice answer. Now, I would like to generate 2-D Binomial Measure but I have faced difficulties in implementing this.

A 1-D case can be generated as follows:

> The binomial measure is a probability measure which is defined conveniently via a recursive construction. Start by splitting $ I := [0, 1] $ into two subintervals $ I_0 $ and $ I_1 $ of equal length and assign the masses $ m_0 $ and $ m_1 = 1 - m_0 $ to them. With the two subintervals one proceeds in the same manner and so forth: at stage two, e.g. the four subintervals $ I_{00}, I_{01}, I_{10}, I_{11} $ have masses $ m_0m_0, m_0m_1 m_1m_0 m_1m_1 $ respectively.

[Rudolf H. Riedi. Introduction to Multifractals](http://www.stat.rice.edu/~riedi/Publ/PDF/intro.pdf)

Intuitively the generalization in 2-D seems easy. Instead of intervals on a unit segment, in 2-D we have a unit square, that recursively splits into four subsquares with masses m0, m1, m2, m3 given m0 + m1 + m2 + m3 = 1, then into 16 subintervals, 64, etc.

---

MWE (1-D case):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import var

def binom_measuare(iterations, p=0.4, current_layer=None):

    var('m0 m1')

    if current_layer is None:
        current_layer = [1]

    next_layer = []

    for item in current_layer:
        next_layer.append(m0*item)
        next_layer.append(m1*item)

    if iterations != 0:
        return binom_measuare(iterations - 1, current_layer=next_layer)

    else:
        return [i.subs(m0, p).subs(m1, 1 - p) for i in next_layer]
```

Let's plot the output

```
y = binom_measuare(iterations=12)
x = [(i+1) / len(y) for i in range(len(y))]

x = [0] + x
y = [0] + y

plt.plot(x, y)
```

MWE for 2-D case:

```
def binom_measuare_2D(iterations, p1=0.4, p2=0.2, p3=0.3, p4=0.1, current_layer=None):

    var('mx0 mx1 my0 my1')

    if current_layer is None:
        current_layer = [1]

    next_layer = []

    for item in current_layer:
        next_layer.append(mx0*item)
        next_layer.append(mx1*item)
        next_layer.append(my0*item)
        next_layer.append(my1*item)

    if iterations != 0:
        return binom_measuare_2D(iterations-1, p1, p2, p3, p4, next_layer)

    else:
        return [i.subs(mx0, p1).subs(mx1, p2).subs(my0, p3).subs(my1, p4) for i in next_layer]
```

And example of use:

```
import numpy as np

iterat = 1
z = binom_measuare_2D(iterations=iterat, p1=0.1, p2=0.2, p3=0.3, p4=0.4)
z = np.array(z)
z = z.reshape(2**(1 + iterat), 2**(1 + iterat))
print(z)
```

It seems to have right values in the output but I have no idea how to assign values from the list for each coordinate x and y. It returns the values for subsquare, but not for the row of the general square so it can be easily visualized. Let me illustrate what I mean. Let (row index; col index) be the indices of the output array in the example provided above.

It fills according to this pattern:

[image: It fills according to this pattern]

However, I expect it to be filled like this one:

[image: I expect it to be like this one]

Answer (score 1):

In analogy to what I wrote in a previous answer I would suggest, rather than thinking in terms of splitting cells consider replacing each cell with four new cells, a kind of *double mitosis*. The values in the new cells can be calculated like this except that the result would be reshaped to form a 4x4 matrix. The next generation layer would be calculated from the current layer by iterating through the cells of the current layer and placing the 4x4 results into the next generation layer.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('m0 m1 m2 m3')
(m0, m1, m2, m3)
>>> def mitosis(aCell):
...     return ((m0**3, m0**2*m1, m0*m1**2, m1**3), (m0**2*m2, m0*m1*m2, m0*m1*m3, m1**2*m3), (m0*m2**2, m0*m2*m3, m1*m2*m3, m1*m3**2), (m0**3, m2**2*m3, m2*m3**2, m3**3))
... 
>>> first = (m0,m1,m2,m3)
>>> mitosis(first)
((m0**3, m0**2*m1, m0*m1**2, m1**3), (m0**2*m2, m0*m1*m2, m0*m1*m3, m1**2*m3), (m0*m2**2, m0*m2*m3, m1*m2*m3, m1*m3**2), (m0**3, m2**2*m3, m2*m3**2, m3**3))
```

Comment: I do not really see how it can be done for any number of iterations. And again using the code provided the matrix will be filled by subsquares rather than rows

Comment: It's not meant as a full solution.

Comment: This is no good as a solution anyway! New cells will not be functions of the contents of existing cells.